# definition of differential curves on manifolds and their length

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization, arc-length

Let X be an n-dimensional differentiable manifold. A Riemannian metric in X is a family $g = \{ g_p | p \in X \}$ with the following properties: for each $p \in X$ , the map $g_p : T_pX \times T_pX \longrightarrow ℝ$ is an inner product in $T_pX$, and for every differentiable chart (U, h, V) for X with coordinates $(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ in V , the functions
$$g_{ij}: U \longrightarrow ℝ \; \; g_{ij}(p):= g_p (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(p), \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(p))  \; \, 1 \leq i,j \leq n$$
are differentiable.
A curve $\gamma : [a, b] \longrightarrow X$ defined on a closed interval [a, b] is called differentiable if there exist an $\epsilon > 0$
and a differentiable curve $\gamma':(a - \epsilon,b+\epsilon) \longrightarrow X$ such that $\gamma'|_{[a,b]}=\gamma$

(a) Show that a differentiable curve $\gamma[a, b] \longrightarrow X$ defines a geometric tangent vector
$[\gamma](t) \in T_{\gamma (t)}X$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ (Be careful in case t = a or b.)

(b) Let g be a Riemannian metric in X. For a differentiable curve $\gamma : [a, b] \longrightarrow X$ , its
length (with respect to g) $L(\gamma)$ is defined as
$$L(γ) := \int_a^b \sqrt{g_{\gamma (t)} ([\gamma](t), [\gamma](t))} dt$$
where $[\gamma](t) \in T_{\gamma(t)}X$ is as in a). Show that the length of a differentiable curve $\gamma : [a, b] \longrightarrow X$ is independent of the parametrization, i.e. that if $f : [c, d] \longrightarrow [a, b]$ is a diffeomorphism and $\gamma':=γ\circ f$, then $L(\gamma)=L(\gamma') $.}

For a), my answer would be: For every $t \in [a,b]$, we can define $\gamma^{t}: \gamma' |_{(t-\epsilon, t+\epsilon)}: (-\epsilon, + \epsilon) \longrightarrow X$. This is a differentiable curve in X.
But this is surely not enough, I do not understand what is to show here.

For b) I don't know how to formulate this. It seems quite obvious, but I don't know how the diffeomorphism interacts with the metric. I would start with $$L(\gamma') = \int_c^d \sqrt{g_{\gamma'(t)} ([\gamma'](t), [\gamma'](t)) dt}$$

Comment: For b) you have to apply the transformation rule for one dimensional integrals, applied to a reparametrization of the curve.

Comment: This has got to be the worst notation I've ever seen. We have a function $\gamma$ of $t$ and rather than using $\gamma'(t)$ to denote its derivative (as a tangent vector at the appropriate point of the manifold), we're using $\gamma'$ to denote a function and $[\gamma]$ to denote the tangent vector???? The professor who made up this notation must be a joy to learn from! [I say this as someone who's taught for about 40 years!]

Comment: @Ted Shifrin 
Yes.. Because of the corona crisis we just have the script and nothing else to study with. Great fun. If you know a good book or script about differential geometry that you can recommend, I would be really greatful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show that arc length $L(\gamma)$ of a curve is unchanged after reparametrization?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142889/how-can-i-show-that-arc-length-l-gamma-of-a-curve-is-unchanged-after-reparam)

Comment: The question about textbook recommendations for differential geometry were asked here many times on MSE. Just type "differential geometry textbook" in the search box on the top of this webpage.